# Computing the phase spectrum of a signal

Tags: java, fft, dft

Using the output from either JTransform, or JWave, how should the phase spectrum be computed?

Do I simply write a similar method, but instead I compute the phase using:
`Math.atan2(im / re) * Math.PI * 180`?

I've used the following to calculate the magnitude spectrum:

```
@Override
public void computeSpectrum()
{
    // The spectrum into which we store the data
    super.spectrum = new double[signal.getSampledAmplitudes().length >> 1];

  // Compute the magnitude spectrum of the signal
  double re = 0, im = 0;
  for (int bin = 0; bin < spectrum.length - 1; ++bin) {
       re = super.frequencyDomain[2 * bin];
       im = super.frequencyDomain[2 * bin + 1];
       super.spectrum[bin] = Math.sqrt(re * re + im * im);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can compute the phase spectrum in radians with a similar loop as you've used for the magnitude spectrum :

```
double re = 0, im = 0;
for (int bin = 0; bin < spectrum.length - 1; ++bin) {
   re = super.frequencyDomain[2 * bin];
   im = super.frequencyDomain[2 * bin + 1];
   super.spectrum[bin] = Math.atan2(im, re);
```

}

If you prefer a result in degrees simply convert the phases with [`toDegrees()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toDegrees(double))

```
...
   super.spectrum[bin] = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(im, re));
```

Comment: Will this yield a both positive and negative phase spectrum? Or do I have to 'unwrap' the phase?

Comment: As per `atan2` documentation: "This method computes the phase *theta* by computing an arc tangent of y/x in the range of *-pi* to *pi*."

Comment: To get rid of noise in the phase spectrum, would I compute the amplitude (sqrt(re * re * im * im)) beforehand, and discard it it's below a certain threshold, or would I do this directly to the phase value (Math.atan2(im, re))?

Comment: If you are trying to isolate sections with a strong coherent signal having a relatively slow varying phase from otherwise weaker noise with randomly fluctuating phase, then the former would be the way to go (ie thresholding based on computed amplitude)

Comment: Its to get rid of float / double rounding issues.

Comment: Then you could round to the nearest "x" degrees with something like `x*Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(im,re))/x)`